# Drawing maps without base images

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, mapkit, draw

I would like to draw a series of maps in an iOS application.  Preferably, without using any image files as a base.

For example, I want to draw a map of the United States with states and counties outlined.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

By *draw*, I mean draw the map in code.  Maybe using Apple's Map kit API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look in here
http://planet.openstreetmap.org
to get the data. Then you can use the 2d graphics libraries to draw it.